# React with GSAP and ScrollMagic - Tween is not valid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, gsap

I'm trying to trigger the reveal animation of my image for each section scroll and i'm doing that with GSAP + ScrollMagic.

The problem is that i'm getting an error saying that the the tween object is not valid.

```
ERROR calling method 'setTween()': Supplied argument is not a valid TweenObject
```

And that's the animation code that i want to trigger when the component mounts:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const scrollControler = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    const imageReveal = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".image-container:after");
    const tl = new TimelineLite();
    const tween = tl.to(imageReveal, {
      duration: 1,
      cssRule: { width: "0%" },
      ease: "power2.easeInOut",
      paused: true
    });

    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: ".image-section",
      triggerHook: 0
    })
      .setTween(tween)
      .addTo(scrollControler);
  }, []);
```

Why my tween is invalid?

That's the sandbox with the code **(Go to the /scroll route)**: https://codesandbox.io/embed/reveal-effect-with-reactjs-and-greensock-5i8pp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I'm not a ScrollMagic expert (we at GreenSock don't really recommend using it - you can get the same effect without using it), but I'm guessing it wants you to pass in either a regular tween (i.e. TweenLite.to()) or a timeline (like tl) to the .setTween() function.

Comment: It also looks like you're mixing GSAP 3 and GSAP 2 formatting. Which are you using? For future reference, you're more likely to get a faster response over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/) FYI.

Comment: I'm using GSAP 3. And i'm passing a timeline to the setTween()

Comment: According to the code you supplied above, you're attempting to pass a tween of a timeline to the .setTween() function, not the timeline itself.

Comment: Now i added a tween to the setTween function instead of a timeline. But it's strange because the animation is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 
I had to install the scrollmagic-plugin-gsap dependency to make Scroll Magic work with the GSAP 3.

In the beggining of the file we have to register Scroll Magic with Gsap. If not, errors like "TweenMax was not defined" will appear.

```
import * as ScrollMagic from "scrollmagic";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollMagicPluginGsap } from "scrollmagic-plugin-gsap";

ScrollMagicPluginGsap(ScrollMagic, gsap);
```

Instead of creating a timeline, you have to pass directly a tween to the setTween method of the Scene.

```
.setTween(imageReveal, 0.4, { scale: 0, autoAlpha: 0 })
```